# Multiple Elements using Javascript, only first works

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a Javascript accordion component, which is functioning well. The issue I am having is when I have more than one on a page, only the first is working. How can I adjust my Javascript (no jQuery) to allow for this? This is the first of many components (tabs etc.) so a general explanation of where I am going wrong would be great. The elements will be added by a CMS so I can't really use IDs in this case.

This is a pen:
https://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/KmeZgG

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
div.accordion {
  .accordion-header {
    cursor: pointer;
    &.active {

    }
  }
  .accordion-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 400ms;
    &.active {
      overflow: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function toggle() {
    if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) {
        this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        var elementHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
        this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elementHeight + 'px';
    }

    // Toggle `active` class
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
}

  var accordion = document.querySelector('div.accordion');
  var header = accordion.getElementsByClassName('accordion-header');

  for (var i = 0, len = header.length; i < len; i++) {
    header[i].addEventListener('click', toggle);
  }

});
```

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`document.querySelectorAll('div.accordion .accordion-header');`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj339CR7_HTAhXKKo8KHcR9DNwQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FquerySelectorAll&usg=AFQjCNGw4XxpSz-PKB1SUB1yNenuYzkpUw) Mention all the selector inside the `querySelectorAll` .No need to add extra with `className` for `.accordion-header`

[**Updated Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmGyBy)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function toggle() {
    if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
      var elementHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
      this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elementHeight + 'px';
    }

    // Toggle `active` class
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  var accordion = document.querySelectorAll('div.accordion .accordion-header');
  for (var i = 0, len = accordion.length; i < len; i++) {
    accordion[i].addEventListener('click', toggle);
  }

});
```

```css
div.accordion .accordion-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.accordion .accordion-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 400ms;
  transition: max-height 400ms;
}

div.accordion .accordion-content.active {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis.
      Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem,
      animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum
      magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis.
      Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem,
      animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum
      magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```